# Laravel SQLite doesn't deleting in cascade

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-testing

I am using the SQLite in memory to test my Laravel application.
Then i define one table Enterprise this way:

```
    Schema::create('Enterprise', function(Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->integer('address_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable();
                $table->foreign('address_id')->references('id')
->on('Address')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
```

the address schema:

```
Schema::create('Address', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

But, when i run the test

```
$emp = Enterprise::find(1)->first();
$emp->delete();
$this->assertEquals(0, Enterprise::all()->count());
$this->assertEquals(0, Address::all()->count());
```

the test fails in the second assert, it is not deleting in cascade :(

Anyone knows the solution ??

Comment: O cascade é pra quando deletar o Endereço, e não a empresa

Comment: @VagnerdoCarmo, please keep your answers in English. And you can go ahead and write an answer as it seems that your comment was a solution.

Comment: I'm sorry... "cascading delete will be effective when you delete an Address, not an Enterprise"